# Does the order of the languages matter in the HTTP Accept-language field?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-accept-language

I was wondering if the order of the actual languages in the Accept-language matters. For example, if our HTTP GET message contained the header:

```
Accept-Language: en-us, en-gb;q=0.2, en;q=0.3, fr, fr-ch, da, fi
```

...would the browser prefer Traditional French (fr) over Swiss French (fr-ch) even though they both have no Relative Quality Factor q mentioned, and hence would be 1.

Answer (score 2):

No, the ordering does not matter.

Comment: Do you know the RFC that supports this? Thanks!

Comment: Both RFC 2616, and the document that will replace it.

Comment: Yes, the actual place with the answer is [RFC 2616, section 14.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4).

Comment: No, what matters is RFC 7231.

Answer (score 2):

When I implemented this, I used a stable sort so that values with the same relative q-value would stay in the same relative order. I believe this is logical and probably [reflects the intention of the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5):

> Note that some recipients treat the order in which language tags are
> listed as an indication of descending priority, particularly for tags
> that are assigned equal quality values (no value is the same as q=1).
> However, this behavior cannot be relied upon.  For consistency and to
> maximize interoperability, many user agents assign each language tag
> a unique quality value while also listing them in order of decreasing
> quality.  Additional discussion of language priority lists can be
> found in [Section 2.3 of RFC4647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-2.3).

As an example of where this behaviour might be desirable, if you have a caching layer/middleware and you are handling the `Accept*` headers in an unstable way (e.g. possibly random selection if they all have the same q-value), while you might not be technically doing anything wrong, but the results would be unpredictable and it might cause problems in the caching layer and a poor user experience (e.g. language changing between pages for no obvious reason).